# Array with strings on the basis of another array with objects [JS/TypeScript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I would like to create new array with strings on the basis of existing array with objects, where Employee class includes `firstName` field:

```
assignees: Array<Employee>;
options: string[];
```

I tried do this in this way:

```
this.options = this.assignees.forEach(value => value = value.firstName);
```

But `type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string[]'`

Could someone please assist?

Comment: because `forEach` function doesn't return anything. Use `map` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forEach()` method just executes a provided function once for each array element.

You could try to do it with `map()`. That's I guess is the right way to do such tasks.

```
// here is how it could look like
this.options = this.assignees.map(value => value.firstName);
```

The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Happy hacking :)